# django user model and custom primary key field

Tags: python, django

Django by default makes a primary key field on each model named "`id`", with a type of `AutoField`. On my models, I'm overriding this to use a custom `UUIDField` as the primary key by using the "`primary_key`" attribute. I would also like the `User` model in `django.contrib.auth` to have a `UUIDField` as the primary key, but this doesn't seem to be possible without changing the `User` model source code.

Is there any recommended way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> this doesn't seem to be possible without changing the User model source code.

Correct. Unless you are willing to change (or replace) `User` there isn't a way.

One (tenuous, hackish) way to do this would be to attach an `UserProfile` for each `User` instance. Each `User` should have exactly *one* `UserProfile`. You can then add your `UUIDField` to the profile. You will still have to do custom querying to translate from `UUIDField` to `id`.

If you don't like the name `UserProfile` you can rename it suitably. The key is that you have a one-to-one relationship to `User`.

Comment: I figured that would be the case. Thanks.

Comment: Note this answer is long outdated. See Soviuts answer instead.

Answer (score 10):

With the release of Django 1.5, the authentication backend now supports custom user models:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

An email field can be used as the username field and the [primary_key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key) argument can be set on it:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True, primary_key=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Comment: You don't need `db_index=True`.
"Note that when unique is True, you don’t need to specify db_index, because unique implies the creation of an index."
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#unique

Answer (score 5):

One could leverage just the `AbstractUser` and make the following changes

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True, db_index=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FILEDS = ['name']
```