# How to set username as ForeignKey in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-1.11

How to set username as ForeignKey in Django module.
is bellow method is correct?

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column="user")
```

i cannot use ID as ForeignKey because my old db have username as ForeignKey.(I need to migrate the the old Data)

Comment: maybe this link can help...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641483/django-user-model-and-custom-primary-key-field

Comment: That's documented: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field

Comment: And you should really migrate your schema and data indeed, at least if you value your data...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers is this correct user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field="username")

Comment: @Kombuwa did you try it ?

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field="username")
```

> The field on the related object that the relation is to. By default,
>   Django uses the primary key of the related object. If you reference a
>   different field, that field must have unique=True.